# passing data between c++ to c

Tags: c++, c

Hi I have two projects: one to get data from a joystick, written in VC++; those data will send to another program client via udp, which is written in C with compiler gcc.

I try this code:
VC++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
 extern "C" int cfunc(int);

int main() {
  int result, y;

  y=5;
  result=cfunc(y);  /* by value */

  if (y==5 && result==6)
printf("It worked!\n");
return 0;
}
```

but when I compiled it with Visual Studio 2010 there were some errors:

```
Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cfunc referenced in function _main
Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

and my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

cfunc(int newval)
{
  ++newval;
  return newval;
}

main()
{ 
 int y;
 cfunc(y);
 printf(" %i ",y);
 }
```

can compiled

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Please **show the errors**, because we can't guess at what appears on your screen.

Comment: Are you missing return type on the C definition?

Comment: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cfunc referenced in function _main F:\daniel\client udp\client udp\client udp.obj
Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals F:\daniel\client udp\Debug\client udp.exe 1

Comment: Wait, you're trying to call a function compiled with GCC from an application compiled with Visual Studio 2010?  How is UDP involved?  Please edit the question to be clearer, it makes no sense.

Comment: I put return 0; but the error were still the same

Comment: @MooingDuck My joystick program is in Vcc and my  udp client server is in C, I want to put data from joystick to udp client. I want to control robot in a server.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably a linker error, as you have not compiled the C code file yet, and the C++ code linking depends on the C code already existing as a linkable object.  Try compiling the C file first, and then having the C++ link against that object file.

Comment: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cfunc referenced in function _main F:\daniel\client udp\client udp\client udp.obj
Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals F:\daniel\client udp\Debug\client udp.exe 1

Comment: @dchellaram: Maybe an explanation on how to mark a function to be imported/exported, and how to link two projects?

Comment: sorry I was wrong to put error code, I try to compile C but the error message is appear: I try to compile C program but the error : /tmp/ccWzqaOM.o:pas.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `_cfunct'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Where is the function `cfunct()` defined?

Comment: I think cfunct() is in c, but I am not sure because I just copy n paste from the website [link] http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.ceea400%2Fceea418021.htm

Comment: @Limavolt as @tangrs points out, you have a typographical error in your code; `cfunct()` in main() should probably be `cfunc()`

Comment: @tangrs thank you I did not see it, yes you are right, Now in C program is not compiled, but when I compiled the VC++ program still have the same errors